# How can configurate headers in azure web app?

Tags: angular, azure, web-applications, http-headers, azure-web-app-service

I need to add some security headers on the server side, specifically they are X-Content-Type-Options and CSP headers, the headers were added to the project using meta tags, but this does not return the headers information in the headers section of "Response Headers" in dev tools, and it needs to be displayed here for security validation.

Is there a way to do it through the azure portal for a web app or any configuration file in angular?

The project is made with Angular(11)
P.S. I'm new to angular and so I'm not familiar with some aspects of the project and the framework.

Comment: How you set headers depends entirely on your backend stack. Angular is frontend so definitely *not* there.

Comment: Similar question asked on Microsoft Q&A. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/960126/index.html

Answer (score 0):

In App Service, TLS/SSL termination happens at the network load balancers, so all HTTPS requests reach your app as unencrypted HTTP requests.

You could control (on all response headers) and include to return HSTS policy header explicitly. There is no App Service feature to enforce such policy on user's behalf.
Just to highlight, App Services HttpsOnly is limited to redirect Http-Https but not extend to forcing single HSTS policy to all your users.

You may take a look at this similar discussion [App service security headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/217670/app-service-security-headers.html).